# Dynamically rank a column based on filters

Tags: powerbi, dax

In my Power BI I have the following table

[image]

What I want is that when you create a graph and have a filter, the ranking column is modified. An example would be that when I change the ranking and select center, I get it like this:

```
  site    | region | nro_trabajos | ranking
----------+--------+--------------+------
OCCORO    | centro | 58           | 1
PILCOMAYO | centro | 59           | 2
SICAYA    | centro | 71           | 3
```

.
.
etc

I generate a table that gives me the following ranking. but has ties

[image]

the measure is rank_measure, as this image shows

[image]

that I can add in this measure so that the tiebreaker is with the alphabetical order of the "site" column and that it still has the region filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A calculated column cannot be dynamic with respect to slicers or filters, but you definitely can create a dynamic ranking **measure**.

```
ranking =
RANKX (
    ALLSELECTED ( Table1 ),
    Table1[nro_trabajos],
    MAX ( Table1[nro_trabajos] )
)
```

---

**Edit:**
If you want to do tiebreaking, I think the simplest way is to first create a `UniqueRank` calculated column:

```
UniqueRank =
RANKX (
    Table1,
    FORMAT ( Table1[nro_trabajos], "0000" ) & Table1[region] & Table1[site]
)
```

You put each column that makes up a unique row in the order you want to rank by, formatting any numbers by padded with sufficient zeros so that the numeric ordering matches the alphabetic ordering.

Then simply use this calculated column `UniqueRank` instead of `nro_trabajos` in the measure I gave above:

```
ranking =
RANKX (
    ALLSELECTED ( Table1 ),
    Table1[UniqueRank],
    MAX ( Table1[UniqueRank] )
)
```

Comment: Hi Alexis, but how would you do when you have two values with the same data? how would one greater than another

Comment: They'll show as a tie (note the [ties options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/rankx-function-dax) of `skip` or `dense`).

Comment: Yes, that's what happens, there is a tie. But what I want is for them to break, as it would be in those cases?

Comment: How should it break ties?

Comment: Yes, how do you want duplicates to be ordered? It's possible break the tie, but you have to specify how. Is there anything to distinguish the rows?

Comment: I will update my publication so that the column that is used to break tie will be seen

Comment: in the current image, how could you tiebreaker with the name of the site?

Comment: You can break a tie by simply adding Rand() to the end of your measure. Rand() will add a random number between 0 and 1the current value breaking your ties.

Comment: hello alexis, the first example you gave me use it, but I get some results tied, as seen in the image I just published in my publication, the measure rank_measure is the ranking, then my query would be that I can add in this measure so that the tiebreaker is with the alphabetical order of the "site" column and that it still has the region filter?

Comment: You didn't use `UniqueRank` instead of `nro_trabajos` as I suggested in my edit.